# How to plot my confusion matrix after fitting my model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

**How to plot the confusion matrix after fitting my model?**

**this is how my database is:**

```
train_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TCC_FILES/New_Dataset/train'
test_path  = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TCC_FILES/New_Dataset/test'
valid_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TCC_FILES/New_Dataset/valid'

#New code

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input, horizontal_flip = True,
                                              width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                              height_shift_range = 0.2) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT), classes=['0_NoCancer', '1_Cancer'], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path, target_size=(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT), classes=['0_NoCancer', '1_Cancer'], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT), classes=['0_NoCancer', '1_Cancer'], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)
```

````
model.fit(train_batches,
          steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(float(18522) / float(BATCH_SIZE)),
          epochs = 20,callbacks=[early_stop,reduce_lr,checkpoint_callback],
          validation_steps=np.ceil(float(2058) / float(BATCH_SIZE)),
          validation_data = valid_batches)```
````

Answer (score 0):

hey my friend if you wand evaluated your model you should train it before
and after use this code in sklearn

> confusion_matrix(predictions.argmax(axis=1), y_test.argmax(axis=1))

ites difrent in code

Comment: Yes, I'm training the model first and then I want to get the predicted values and the actual values to pass on my confusion matrix to do the plotting.